# Convert number to time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a large CSV-file with a column called TIME. It's written as 1318 and I would like to use Python/Pandas to convert the data as 13:18 and see it as time instead of int64.

I've tried something like this but this is not what I want:

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'])
```

Because I get this:

```
    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001318                           
    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001041                              
    1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000853
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you pass a [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) param to `to_datetime` you will get the following:

```
In [111]:

t="1318"
pd.to_datetime(t, format='%H%M')
Out[111]:
Timestamp('1900-01-01 13:18:00')
```

However, I don't know if you want a default date here.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `format` keyword argument to `pd.to_datetime` method.

It is a string with the usual [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) syntax.

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
  def extractTime(l):
    tt = (l.split(' ')[1]).split('.')[1][-4:];
    return tt[:2] + ':' + tt[-2:];

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      l = "1970-01-01 00:00:00.000001318";
      print extractTime(l);
```

It will print out "13:18" for the test case.