# How to read in a number from a csv as a time in Pandas

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a csv that I'm trying to parse with Pandas, and there's a column that contains a 24 hour time, but it's just a simple number in the csv:

| CaseNumber | OccurDate | OccurTime | OffenseCategory | OffenseType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20-X5397620 | 1/1/20 | 345 | Assault Offenses | Simple |

[image: The column OccurTime is what I'm trying to parse as a time]

Should I join it with OccurDate so I can do the normal datetime parsing with Pandas?

Comment: This is time in minutes?

Comment: Yeah, it should be in 24 hr time, so 53 should be 0053, 158 0158, etc.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put there sample of your CSV in text form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I think this answer is the one I want:
[Convert number to time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070548/convert-number-to-time-in-python/30070634#30070634)

All I'm looking for is the time, and the date part of the datetime is irrelevant for my needs.

Also this answer to help pad some of those values that are only two digits out to 4: [Add Leading Zeros to Strings in Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836277/add-leading-zeros-to-strings-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

first of all, please check the "OccureTime" dataType using df.info(). for me it does not look 24H data column.

Comment: 5   OccurTime        59528 non-null  int64

Comment: you can convert int dateTime to datetime format easily using:

`import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'int_date': [20210101, 20210102, 20210103]})

df2['formatted_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['int_date'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')

print(df2)`

But, I think this column is not for dateTime, It seems the count of occurrence(repeat) of this record event. Can you please check again the business behind this column?

Comment: @Amanda_Panda Do you still need support here?

Comment: Nope, gonna accept my own comment below as the answer in about an hour. Thank you for your help!