# Convert column of Dataframe to time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, timestamp

I have the following Dataframe:
[image: Dataframe]

Now i want to convert the column "ABZEIT" to time format. So the first rows would be:

13:05 15:40 14:20 16:30 07:40 12:05 17:15

Comment: Here is how :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62070759/how-to-convert-string-hhmm-to-time-in-python

Comment: @Tocy777 older dupe: [Convert number to time in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070548/convert-number-to-time-in-python) - there are probably more.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that first defines a `to_time()` function then apply it to the dataframe by using `map()`.

```py
from datetime import time

def to_time(t: int) -> time:
    t = f"{t:04}"  # add the leading zero if needed
    return time(int(t[:2]), int(t[2:]))

df["ABZEIT"] = df["ABZEIT"].map(to_time)
```